# Setting things to undefined

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I see this throughout our codebase:

```
(function(undefined) {
    var foo = {
        dirtyRow: undefined,
        dirtyCells: undefined,
        ...
        clearDirty: function () {
            this.dirtyRow = undefined;
            this.dirtyCells = undefined;
        }
    }
})();
```

Can someone articulate for me what's wrong with this? What should we be doing instead?

Comment: At least you can see what the object can/should contain. Though setting them to `null` might be more semantical.

Comment: @pst: Because it's more difficult to differ between something that doesn't exist and something that has been defined as undefined. I guess opinions differ on this.

Comment: @pimvdb Oops, I missed a critical part of the code: my issue is that it uses `undefined` as a *parameter name*, which can cause all sorts of confusion!

Comment: @pst wouldn't his/her object properties need a value? for them i'd use null as for the others i'd just do this: this. dirtyRow; this.dirtyCells; for vars when you don't include a value(nor an = sign) it will automatically be undefined his argument should also be null

Comment: @codewombat `undefined` is a value, it all just comes down to the semantics given I guess. I do not really see a reason for one of the other (except it may be easier to test for the shape with `o.p != null` vs `!(p in o)`). It is unfortunate of the use of `undefined` as a parameter name here, as that adds a whole different issue/reason :(

Comment: @pst yeah i agree, undefined as a perimeter is defiantly a "no-no"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` makes more sense than `undefined` in this context, because you are defining the variables but are not yet assigning a value to them.

However both `null` and `undefined` are falsy values, so for the most part the behaviour will be the same.

`null` is a keyword though, whereas `undefined` is not. So `null` would be more "reliable", even if you are using the argument to ensure that `undefined` is in fact undefined.

Comment: I can agree with the former, but not the latter. If the value `undefined` evaluates to, even if valid, is altered, then the programming environment has forfeited its contract. I believe this is no different than having 1+1 return 3 on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is wrong, is that you shouldn't use the `undefined` "constant" at all, until all browsers are up to the latest version of the Javascript specs.

Lately the specifications changed it to a real constant, but all older browsers follow the older specs, where it's a writable value. That means that the `undefined` identifier can be changed to a different value, which of course would make that code do something that was not intended.

Comment: It has been passed as the infamous argument here, which should work fine.

Comment: I beg to differ about the "constant" stuff (programming is about working with a set of assumptions and if they are violated then the contract is off). However, what I *do* believe is that *one should not use `undefined` as a parameter or variable name* (even in an attempt to "fix" the constant issue).

Comment: @pst: Naturally you can't check for everything and avoid anything, but there are some things that you should avoid as they are not properly specified/implemented.

Comment: @Guffa I avoid altering the assumptions (e.g. keeping the expected contracts valid). For instance, `True,False = False,True` is *entirely valid* in earlier Python versions as they were not reserved. Does that mean that `True` and `False` should be avoided in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with this code. This approach is used to ensure that `undefined` is really "undefined", because in non strict mode (ES5) you could override that value (so if you use 3rd party script or a malicious script will be inject in your page).

Basically you have an argument and you call this function without pass any value, so it will be "undefined". You could obtain the same result having:

```
(function(u) {
    var foo = {
        dirtyRow: u,
        dirtyCells: u,
        ...
        clearDirty: function () {
            this.dirtyRow = u;
            this.dirtyCells = u;
        }
    }
})();
```

But, of course, using `undefined` makes more sense.

Comment: I disagree with it making more sense, excepting that it *shows* what is happening here. If the environment establishes that `undefined` evaluates to ... not undefined ... then the environment is already broken. (I would just keep the assumption/rule in place and remove the `undefined` parameter in the original code.) All that aside, does it make sense to set a value to show the "shape" of the object?

Comment: Makes more sense in the way that `undefined` is more "understable" than `u` or something else. In fact, the environment IS broken, you shouldn't be able to redefine `undefined` (it sounds funny even to read). So, this is a workaround to play safe in a language that is broken. In ES5 in strict mode infact, you cannot do that: you get an exception.